# firebird 2.0 with laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, firebird

I need to create website that connects to firebird server. I wasnt told at the beginning that firebird version here is 2.0 and started working with 2.5. I used this [driver](http://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird/). It worked perfectly with firebird 2.5. But now it doesn't seems to work with firebird 2.0. Laravel throws this error:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 47: could not find driver

Is there any chance to make laravel 5.0.34 work with firebird 2.0.7?

Comment: I know nothing about Laravel, but I would expect a driver for Firebird 2.5 to work with Firebird 2.0 (except maybe some edge cases like cancel support). But seriously: convince your client to upgrade to 2.5 or 3.0. Firebird 2.0.7 is end-of-life, meaning it no longer receives updates, and it has a number of known security vulnerablities that allow a remote client to crash the server.

Comment: You might also want to post what code you use to connect with Firebird 2.5, but doesn't work with Firebird 2.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, can it be the problem, that this script `<?php
 echo count(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
 foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver) {
  echo $driver.'<br />'; 
 }
?>` shows 0?